# Using Physics Injector in Starling not working

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, physics

I am trying to use Physics Injector in my starling game and am getting this error on the "." of my

```
static var PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
```

statement. '.' is not allowed here. On the Physics Injector blog is says to "Simply set the static variable PhysInjector.STARLING to true and that’s it!"

Am I setting this in the wrong place or something? What am I doing wrong?

```
        private function injectPhysics():void
    {
        static var PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
        physics = new PhysInjector (stage, new b2Vec2(0, 60), true)
        var floorObject:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(floor, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:false, friction:0.5, restitution:0.5}));
        var presentP:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(present, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:true, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));
    }
```

Comment: take out the words "static var" I don't think they expect you to attempt to redefine the variable, rather just assign it. http://reycogames.com/physinjector/docs/com/reyco1/physinjector/PhysInjector.html#STARLING

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about how the PhysInjector initializes Try this:

```
private function injectPhysics():void {
    PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
    physics = new PhysInjector (stage, new b2Vec2(0, 60), true);
    var floorObject:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(floor, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:false, friction:0.5, restitution:0.5}));
    var presentP:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(present, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:true, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
private function injectPhysics():void {
    physics = new PhysInjector (stage, new b2Vec2(0, 60), true);
    physics.STARLING = true;
    var floorObject:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(floor, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:false, friction:0.5, restitution:0.5}));
    var presentP:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(present, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:true, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));
}
```

Comment: The first one should set the STARLING var to true for all instances of PhysInjector created from that point on. The second one should make the STARLING var true for only the physics instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "static" and "var" namspaces from your code.

```
static var PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
```

should be

```
PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
```